# Segfault in std::function destructor

Tags: c++, c++11, segmentation-fault, std-function, stdbind

I'm currently maintaining a C++ REST Server developed in C++. It provides some features like middleware and routes.

Routes are stored inside an inner structure of the router class:

```
//! The http router
//!
//! allow us to parse route on a server using regex to match the good route for a given url
//! and extract the possible url variables
class router {
private:
    //! routes datas
    //!
    //! contains:
    //! * the regex to parse the routes
    //! * an std::vector with the list of variable inside the routes
    //! * 4 std::function, one for each REST methods
    struct rest_routes {
        std::regex regex;
        std::vector<std::string> vars_name;
        std::pair<std::function<http::response(http::request&)>, std::vector<std::string>> get;
        std::pair<std::function<http::response(http::request&)>, std::vector<std::string>> post;
        std::pair<std::function<http::response(http::request&)>, std::vector<std::string>> put;
        std::pair<std::function<http::response(http::request&)>, std::vector<std::string>> del;
    };
};
```

Everything works well during the execution: routes can be configured and added to the router and if someone request the server on an existing route, callback are executed and the server send a response as expected.

Here is an example of a route configuration where we create a route `/admin/cameras/:cam_id` for an `HTTP DELETE` request:

```
// delete a camera
router.del("/admin/cameras/:cam_id",
           std::bind(&admin_service::remove_camera, service, std::placeholders::_1));
```

In this example, `admin_service::remove_camera` is a member function and `service` is a `shared_ptr`containing a pointer to an `admin_service`object. If someone requests this route, `admin_service::remove_camera` is called.

However, the server segfaults at the end of the execution (when we exit the server).

I have traced the origin of the segfault, and it comes from the destructor of... `std::function`. To be more precise, it happened during the destruction of one of the `std::function` contained in the `std::pair`s `get`, `post`, `put` and `del`.

I can say this because, when I put the following debug code:

```
struct rest_routes {

    ~rest_routes() {
        std::cout << "BEGIN DTOR rest_routes" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "BEGIN get" << std::endl;
        get.first = nullptr;
        std::cout << "END get" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "BEGIN post" << std::endl;
        post.first = nullptr;
        std::cout << "END post" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "BEGIN put" << std::endl;
        put.first = nullptr;
        std::cout << "END put" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "BEGIN del" << std::endl;
        del.first = nullptr;
        std::cout << "END del" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "END DTOR rest_routes" << std::endl;
    }

    std::regex regex;
    std::vector<std::string> vars_name;
    std::pair<std::function<http::response(http::request&)>, std::vector<std::string>> get;
    std::pair<std::function<http::response(http::request&)>, std::vector<std::string>> post;
    std::pair<std::function<http::response(http::request&)>, std::vector<std::string>> put;
    std::pair<std::function<http::response(http::request&)>, std::vector<std::string>> del;
};
```

I got the following output:

```
BEGIN DTOR rest_routes
BEGIN get
END get
BEGIN post
END post
BEGIN put
END put
BEGIN del
Segmentation Fault
```

I can't figure how a std::function can segfault during destruction or assignment...

I first thought that, maybe, `std::function` took a reference to the `std::shared_ptr service` instead of taking it by value and deleted the raw pointer it contains more than once. But when I put some debug output, I can see that the `shared_ptr` counter is incremented after the call to `router.del`.

Does someone have some idea about this issue?

Comment: `I can't figure how a std::function can segfault during destruction or assignment`  Go one step further and isolate the line of code or step that caused the segfault within the destructor.  Then use that as a starting point.

Comment: This is what I did in the second code quote: I just changed the value contained in the `std::function` (`del.first = nullptr`). It causes a segfault during the assignation. This assignment operator call may have some operations which are similar to the operations of the destructor (like destructing internal attributes). But I have now idea of how to go further now, except opening the standard library source code.

Comment: Try to give raw pointer to `std::function` instead of `shared_ptr`. Like this `... std::bind( &admin_service::remove_camera, service.get(), std::placeholders::_1)`

Comment: The result is the same. I have also tried to pass directly an object (`std::bind(&admin_service::remove_camera, *(service.get()), std::placeholders::_1)`) but the segfault continue to happen at the same location. And obviously, when I remove the routes configuration, the program exits properly.

Comment: @SimonNinon Is the `del` instance still valid?  That's the only way I can see where a pointer assignment would crash, and that is the underlying object holding the pointer is invalid.

Comment: valgrind is your friend

Comment: were you ever able to figure this out ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a memory corruption issue. I would try:

- Running it under [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html). If possible, because `valgrind` emulates CPU so that the application runs ~50 times slower under a single virtual thread. And errors caused by race conditions may not manifest under `valgrind`.
- Use gcc/clang [address sanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer) by re-compiling and linking with `-fsanitize=address` command line option. This one works amazingly because of its relatively low [overhead](https://developerblog.redhat.com/2014/12/02/address-and-thread-sanitizers-gcc/): *a program instrumented with Address Sanitizer would typically run twice as slow as its non-instrumented counterpart and would typically consume 20% more memory*.